# Parsing ResultExecutedContext in ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

In my controller, The JsonResult method looks as follows:

```
public JsonResult MyTestJsonB()
{
    return Json(new {Name = "John", Age = "18", DateOfBirth = DateTime.UtcNow}, "text/plain", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In my following OnResultExecuted Method of Attribute class....

```
    public class JsonResultAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {

        public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
....
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to parse filterContext as follows. How do I accomplish the following??

1. I want to be able to detect that the result is of type System.Web.MVC.JsonResult.
2. Within the Result, I want to be able to dig into the Data Property
3. With Property, I want to be able to detect if my passed in object has a property of type DateTime. For example if the object is as follows: { Name = "John", Age = "18", DateOfBirth = {4/24/2014 7:05:58 PM} }, I want to be able to detect that property DateOfBirth is of type DateTime.
4. If it has DateTime, Then I want to take certain action.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `System.Reflection`:

```
public class JsonResultAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

        // Detect that the result is of type JsonResult
        if (filterContext.Result is JsonResult)
        {
            var jsonResult = filterContext.Result as JsonResult;

            // Dig into the Data Property
            foreach(var prop in jsonResult.Value.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
            {
                var propName = prop.Name;
                var propValue = prop.GetValue(jsonResult.Value,null);

                Console.WriteLine("Property: {0}, Value: {1}",propName,     propValue);

                // Detect if property is an DateTime
                if (propValue is DateTime)
                {
                    // Take some action
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do not forget to add `[JsonResultAttribute]` in your action.